# Javascript replace rturned data from server

Tags: javascript, html

I want to format user input on client side only and replace `&lt;br/&gt;` that returned from server to `<br/>` html element.

I have the below javascript code to format user input

```
function HtmlEncode(s){
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
  s = el.innerHTML;
  return replace_chat_tags(s);
}
```

I use the below function to replace url and email from client

```
function replace_chat_tags(chat_body = '') {
  return chat_body
    .replace( /((http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?=\-&_/]+)/g, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>" )
    .replace( /\b([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})\b/gi, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>" )
    .replace( /&lt;br\/&gt;/g, "<br/>" );
}
```

My problem is the above code doesn't replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` when it match it still return `&lt;br\/&gt;`, Can somebody give me a hint on this?
HtmlEncode(chat.message)

Comment: Why not just use `replace("&lt;br/&gt;", "<br />")`? Without a regex.

Answer (score 1):

The Regex should be constructed properly.

```js
k = "&lt;br/&gt"

console.log(k.replace(new RegExp("&lt;br/&gt", "g"), "<br/>"));

console.log(k.replace(new RegExp(/&lt;br\/&gt/, "g"), "<br/>"));
```